# Please ELI5 how the Klein bottle is embedded into $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics

So, I haven't taken upper-level topology and have limited understanding of upper-level linear algebra. I am taking a course in discrete mathematics, and they referred to the Klein bottle.

My understanding of a vector is that it's similar to a number in that is simply represents things mathematically and can be operated on mathematically, if there are $n$ independent "dimensions" and it exists in a vector space. Obviously, these "dimensions" don't have to be spatial.

So, my understanding is that the Klein bottle is not actually an object, it's simply a mathematical "thing" and simply can't exist spatially (4th spatial dimension doesn't exist).

So, can you attempt to give a really simple explanation of how to embed it into 4 dimensions, using some kind of dimension system and vector space?

Any critiques on my understanding of a vector are appreciated as well even a complete re-evaluation of my understanding is appreciated, I would be interested in hearing your perspective on vectors and what they "are" too.

Also, if you could comment on what you think a "number" is and when it can be used would be appreciated as well.
Thank you :)

Comment: “The Klein bottle is not actually an object it’s simply a mathematical ‘thing’”; this is a philosophical nightmare to unwind. But the Klein bottle is as real or as fake to me as just about any other thing in maths, even $3d$ things

Comment: It seems like you’ve just started with linear algebra and want it to describe everything. It can’t, unfortunately

Comment: Reading between the lines a bit it seems your main question/source of confusion is not about the Klein bottle, but about abstractions in general. I think you'd benefit more from a face to face discussion with your professor during office hours around how to accept certain abstractions. For example you note that the Klein bottle is "not actually an object". What does that mean? Is the number "1" somehow more real, more of an object? Can you show me "1"? Or are you showing me "1" *of something*? There are abstractions we are used to and ones we aren't.

Comment: Physical questions belong at phys.SE. To math, $\mathbb R^3$ is just one among other $\mathbb R^n$ spaces, and the Klein bottle is exactly as real (or as non-real) as a sphere or a circle or anything like that.